# #quickfix import failed in windows10

Tags: python, quickfix

system: windows 10,
language: python 3.6.5
I installed the quickfix 1.15.1 by pip install quickfix-1.15.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl downloaded from web.
When I try like:

import quickfix

```
errors:
*Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.6948.78)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 21, in <module>
    _quickfix = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_quickfix')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

And I had installed .Net 5.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that quickfix is correctly installed in your environment and the PYTHONPATH has access to this environment, then you can try to check the option 'Load conda env vars before run?' on Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter.

It's possible that the import is failing because that package is using an environment variable to load the modules, and PyDev by default is not loading this variable before running the script.